# Adding list to JCombobox in java

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a list that has to be added to my jcombobox.

my code is

```
serialportcombobox=new JComboBox<String>();
serialportcombobox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray()));
serialportcombobox.setBounds(125, 80, 220, 25);
serialporttab.add(serialportcombobox);
```

tried this but didnt work.

Im setting the list from another frame and using that list in the combobox.

Code for that is

```
configbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
     {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {

            KeypadConfig key=new KeypadConfig();
            key.setId(serialportlist,hashlist);
            key.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {
               e1.printStackTrace();    
            }
        }
    });
     contentPane.add(keypadconfigbtn);
```

This is used in keypadconfig

```
public void setId(List<String> serialportlist,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> hashlist)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    seriallist=hashlist;
    list=serialportlist;


}
```

but list is null when set to the combobox but in the setid list is not null.how to i add the list in the setid to the combobox.
Please help

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

your first code fragment might be taken from KeypadConfig constructor or a method which is called from a contructor.

If it is the the case, you call setId method after KeypadConfig is fully constructed.so when it is constructing list is null.